# Excel - moving data for duplicate rows to new columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have duplicate rows which represent customers who have bought different items. The item purchased are in one column. I would like to move them to separate columns so that I can import to a different program. So my data looks like something this:

[image: uploaded screenshot of Excel]

```
John  book          
John  ball          
John  bat           
Tom   book          
Tom   bat           
Kate  ball
```

I would like the data on items purchased moved to separate columns, something like this:

```
John   book   ball   bat

Tom    book    -     bat

Kate    -     ball    -
```

Where each of book, ball, and bat has it's own column.

Answer (score 1):

This formula, filled down from `A8`, will list the customer names, removing duplicates:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$6,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(A$7:A7,$A$1:$A$6),0)),"")`

This is an array formula, so it must be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This formula, filled right and down from `B8`, will list the purchases by each customer:

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$6=$A8)*($B$1:$B$6=INDEX($B$1:$B$3,COLUMN(A1))))>0, INDEX($B$1:$B$3,COLUMN(A1)),"")`

[image]

Note that the last formula relies on the fact that `B1:B3` is an ordered list of the purchases.  This is probably coincidental, and a similar list could be located anywhere. If the list were horizontal, instead of vertical, the formula would be simpler.  Say the list was in `E1:G1`, then the formula would be:

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$6=$A8)*($B$1:$B$6=E$1))>0,E$1,"")`

And an array formula similar to the first one, filled right from E1, could list the purchases there:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$6,,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D1:D1,$B$1:$B$6),0)),"")`